# meteor deploy error to aws when use another port

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, meteor, deployment, port

I tried meteor deploy to aws ubuntu for npm mup. While My aws server operating apache server at 80 port. First time, i try deploy at 80 port on my server that was successed, but i realized i was setup apache on my server. So, re-setting mup.json / port:8100 and then try again deploy.. But deploy was failed. Of couse i already add rule from aws security group port.

Here is my error code :

```
 -----------------------------------STDERR-------------------------------
 ARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
 npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
 npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
 npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js   (wd=/opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server)
 sudo: unable to resolve host abab.co.kr
 sudo: unable to resolve host abab.co.kr
 sudo: unable to resolve host abab.co.kr
 sudo: unable to resolve host abab.co.kr
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8100: ��������� ���������
Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.

    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    de`
    ansi-regex@0.2.1 node_modules/ansi-regex

    ansi-styles@1.1.0 node_modules/ansi-styles

    chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk

    escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 node_modules/escape-string-regexp

    has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi

    supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color

    strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi

    eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline

    type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of

    amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine

    meteor-promise@0.7.2 node_modules/meteor-promise

    asap@2.0.4 node_modules/asap

    underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

    source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support

    semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

    promise@7.1.1 node_modules/promise

    source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map

    fibers@1.0.13 node_modules/fibers
    Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
    connected
    meteor stop/waiting
    meteor start/running, process 18745
    Waiting for 15 seconds while app is booting up
    Checking is app booted or not?
    meteor stop/waiting
    meteor start/running, process 18807
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

how can i fix it? if have some idea, let me know your solution!

-----------------------------------update----------------------------------

i fix it, follow comment. but i got a new error msg

here is my error code, somebody any idea about that?

```
 -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
        package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
        npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
        npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
        npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server)
        => Starting meteor app on port:80

        assert.js:93
          throw new assert.AssertionError({
                ^
        AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
            at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
            at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
            at require (module.js:380:17)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
            at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

        => Redeploying previous version of the app

        -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

        To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you check if you are able to telnet or curl to that port 8100

Comment: actually, i forgot open port in ubuntu.. haha.. thx.

Comment: @error2007s 
i got new error. i check node -v at ubuntu. that is 0.10.40  //
but my meteor node -v is 4.4.7/ i think that's problem.. 
Any idea about this?

Comment: i update node version on ubuntu also 4.4.7/ but got a same error. i don't have idea about it how can i fix it ?

Comment: check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38768810/3669687

Comment: this figured out from Luna