# got error trace when meteor deploy to AWS ubuntu with mupx

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, meteor, deployment

I tried meteor deploy to aws ubuntu for npm mupx. When i try deploy to aws ubuntu , i got a error. here is my error code, any idea about this? please help me.

```
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.262760219Z npm WARN deprecated This version of npm lacks support for important features,
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.263078622Z npm WARN deprecated such as scoped packages, offered by the primary npm
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.263608859Z npm WARN deprecated registry. Consider upgrading to at least npm@2, if not the
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.263841265Z npm WARN deprecated latest stable version. To upgrade to npm@2, run:
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.264022091Z npm WARN deprecated 
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.264214145Z npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest-2
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.264388418Z npm WARN deprecated 
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.264582942Z npm WARN deprecated To upgrade to the latest stable version, run:
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.264753708Z npm WARN deprecated 
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.264955187Z npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.265132059Z npm WARN deprecated 
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.265319246Z npm WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your system, you
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.265507812Z npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding commands with `sudo`, or if
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.265698699Z npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.265870846Z npm WARN deprecated 
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.266053678Z npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.266249940Z npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.266454393Z npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.266764265Z npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.266962265Z npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.500691274Z npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.504356284Z npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.507612660Z npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.597973214Z npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.615599841Z => Starting meteor app on port:80
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.675588035Z 
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.675961880Z assert.js:93
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.676233801Z   throw new assert.AssertionError({
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.676351801Z         ^
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677859197Z AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677870250Z     at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677874284Z     at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677892655Z     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677896149Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677898899Z     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677901570Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677904229Z     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677906984Z     at require (module.js:380:17)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677909741Z     at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
[**.**.**.*] 2016-08-04T08:04:44.677912674Z     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

if you have any idea about this deal, just let me know any solution!

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with the same thing today for a few hours.

Your current deployment has node version v0.x.x (hard coded in MupX) and Meteor 1.4 needs v4.4.7. Thats the main reason as far as I know.

How I solved the issue: I got a backup with mongodump, downloaded it to my computer, erased everything from the server, installed [Mup](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up) by KadiraHQ (updated yesterday), did the setup and included this docker image in options:

```
dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base'
```

I did mup deploy then `mongorestore` to import the DB.

You can also check [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7475) and especially the comments by abernix.

Please note that for both pem and path, Mup doesn't let you use ~ in the paths and doesn't give you a searchable error. You need to write the full URL like this:

```
pem: '/Users/luna/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: oh... thank you sooooooo much x100, i got a lot of stress about this problems. Finally, I figured out! i just follow your solution! just added dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base' to mup.json. After that it worked. you're super! you save my life. thx bro!

Comment: Can i ask one more thing?When used 80 port that was successed.But i want to use 8100 port, so i edited mup.js propertis from meteor:{ env:{ PORT : 8100    //. After that i got error. is it incorrect? how can i change port when i deploy meteor or after deploy to aws server, hope you know how to handle this! thx

Comment: @kai no problem. I don't really know how you can change the port of an existing deployment with mup/mupx. I think you should erase the current version and deploy again. Would probably be quicker. If your question is answered, please mark it as resolved. Cheers